# List has no rows for assignment to SObject when tried to Get All Manager Id

Tags: apex, list, set

I have a problem with this code , I trie to get all the list of account for the five manager of the user , I used this code but I get this error :

```
List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

This is my code , some help please

```
  User u1 = [SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE manager.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() 
           or manager.manager.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() 
           or manager.manager.manager.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()
           or manager.manager.manager.manager.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()
           or manager.manager.manager.manager.manager.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() ];

           Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
           ids.add(u1.manager.Id);
           ids.add(u1.manager.manager.Id);
           ids.add(u1.manager.manager.manager.Id);
      
      List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Account WHERE ownerid IN: ids];
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure you get a record, start by matching `Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()` and return the manager fields rather than matching to them:

```
User u = [
    SELECT Id, Manager.Id, Manager.Manager.Id, ...
    FROM User
    WHERE Id: UserInfo.getUserId() 
];

Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
if (u.Manager != null) {
    ids.add(u.Manager.Id);
    if (u.Manager.Manager != null) {
        ids.add(u.Manager.Manager.Id);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get all the 5 level manager from current logged in user, query should ideally be like this:

```
User u1 = [SELECT id, name, manager.Id, manager.manager.Id, manager.manager.manager.Id, manager.manager.manager.manager.Id, manager.manager.manager.manager.manager.Id  FROM user WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() ];
```

Comment: I tried your proposition and modified my query and when I am connected with the first user I get the data but once I am connected by the first manager I don't get any data ( I get an error `Volume_per_station:1 Uncaught (in promise)  "System.StringException" `

Comment: There might be problem with how you are parsing data in javascript. The query should work fine. @Salesforcedev98908